# Wifi is not working after installing MIUI

Tags: wi-fi, miui

I have HTC Desire S and i was using android 4.0.4 ROM from HTC but it was too slow and I decided to install a new ROM - MIUI 3.2.22 for Desire S. When I installed it, my wifi didn't work. I tried to install other versions of MIUI but wifi didn't work in any of them. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem with my Xperia M (C1905) and Miui 4.9.26.
It turned out that the cause was that I didn't wipe the old stock android.

So the solution was:

1. enter TWRP
2. advanced wipe and wipe everything except sd card (I also didn't wipe the last item USB something).
3. Install MIUI again